# UNABLE TO UNSUBSCRIBE HUOBI WEBSOCKET TICKER SUBSCRIPTION

Tags: sockets, websocket, ws, unsubscribe, huobi

I'm trying to unsubscribe from a HUOBI websocket server but the server is keep sending me the datas.
I contacted to support but so far there is no news. Is there anyone who is achieved to unsubscribe?

As far as I checked from their API, this is what should I send for unsubscription.

```
            console.log("Unsubscribing Huobi for symbol: " + symbol)
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                "unsub": `market.${symbol}.ticker`,
                "id": `${symbol}`
            }));
```

And this is how I subscribed;

```
            console.log("Subscribing Huobi for symbol: " + symbol)
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                "sub": `market.${symbol}.ticker`,
                "id": `${symbol}`
            }));
```

Comment: The code you give us doesn't tell us much. Can you provide more code? Which library are you using?

Comment: Hi! I'm coding on node.js
According to API document is crystal clear tough: https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/spot/v1/en/#introduction-10

Although, I send the mentioned data with my ws socket instance, it is not working.

Comment: You should put ***node.js*** as one of your tags so that the ***node.js*** community sees your question and can help you. This will also avoid be clearer for other coding communities to know what language you are coding in. Please read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: It's seems like a Huobi problem not a coding. I just wondered if anyone faced the same issue.

Comment: I just received a confirmation from Huobi support. They solved the issue. Now, I'm able to be unsubscribed properly. FYI

Comment: Great. Please put this information in an answer and accept the answer so the question can be closed with a solution found.

Answer (score -1):

I just received a confirmation from Huobi support. They solved the issue. Now, I'm able to be unsubscribed properly. FYI –